# Why is there a line in English in Loki's song?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki, loki-2021

In Episode 3, Loki sings an Asgardian drinking song:

The lyrics are as follows:

> Når hun synger hun synger kom hjem
>
> Men trærne danser og fosserne
> stanser
>
> When she sings, she sings come home
>
> When she sings, she sings
> come home
>
> Men trærne danser og fossene stanser
>
> Når hun synger hun synger kom
> hjem
>
> Men trærne danser og fosserne stanser
>
> When she sings, she sings
> come home
>
> When she sings, she sings come home
>
> When she sings, she
> sings come home
>
> When she sings, she sings come home
>
> I stormsvarte fjell, jeg vandrer alene
>
> Over isbreen tar
> jeg meg frem I eplehagen står møyen den vene
>
> Og synger "når kommer du
> hjem?"
>
> Men trærne danser og fossene stanser
>
> Når hun synger, hun synger kom
> hjem
>
> Men trærne danser og fossene stanser
>
> When she sings, she sings
> come home
>
> When she sings, she sings come home

Most of the song is in "Asgardian" (which is Norwegian in practice, or so I'm told). But then there's one line which is in English. **Why is that?**

I doubt there is an in-universe explanation, since I doubt we can make sense of the fact Loki and Sylvie are not speaking Asgardian with one another rather than English. But even out-of-universe, what is the point of having one line in English? It's not like it's crucial to the story, or that we learn anything obvious from it. (Of course, you can try to analyze it, but you can also google the meaning of the rest of the lyrics).

Comment: I actually thought that it meant something: "When she sings, she sings come home" meant If she [Sylvie] sings with them, she will come home [i.e, accept/understand Loki and join him]

Comment: What a coincidence.. Possibly, Asgardians borrowed some words from English when they were acting god on Earth.

Comment: Why is there a line in English in Loki's song? [Je ne sais pas pourquoi.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Je_ne_sais_pas_pourquoi)

Answer (score 3):

The repeated line appears to have been translated, by Loki, from Asgardian into English. This allows his audience to take part in the song, by singing part of the chorus in a language they understand.

Note that the line itself is also present, in its *untranslated* form, elsewhere in the song.

> Over isbreen tar jeg meg frem I eplehagen står møyen den vene
> Og synger "når kommer du hjem?"
> Men trærne danser og fossene stanser
> **Når hun synger, hun synger kom hjem** (*when she sings, she sings come home*)
> Men trærne danser og fossene stanser
> When she sings, she sings come home
> When she sings, she sings come home

For the record, this is a common feature of [real-world songs intended for both a home and international audience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mon_alli%C3%A9e_(The_Best_in_Me)).